# SUM of a Calculated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on a query that I can't seem to fix;
I need to return a total value of Fees for this table

```
ID | somevalue | month
xx | 33        | 3
xx | 33        | 3
```

I need to put out '66', grouped by month - however as the somevalue field is calculated how would I go about summing it?

Comment: Consider reading [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT month,sum(somevalue) 
FROM(Your query that calculates the SOMEVALUE column here) TMP
GROUP BY month
```

Its a simple group by query, put the query that calculates somevalue inside the FROM clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, however that still doesnt let me add a new column with a total of the somevalue field?